# regex check if a character exists in combination with other characters, but not by its self

Tags: regex

```
^\[[FfMmHhTt/]+\]
```

The above RegEx will detect any combination of "m", "f", "h", "t" or "/" within square brackets, upper or lower case, just as it should. However, I would like to modify it so that the forward slash character cannot by found in the square brackets by itself. For example, `[F/m]`, `[t/m/h]` or `[Hh]` should still pass, but `[/]` or `[///]` should not. 
Leading and trailing slashes such as [/t] or [h/m/] should also fail to match.
Can't find any regex tutorials that describe such a thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could phrase the pattern as:

```
^\[[FfMmHhTt](?:/?[FfMmHhTt])*\]$
```

Here is an explanation:

```
^                  from the start of the string
\[                 match a literal opening square bracket
[FfMmHhTt]         followed by [fmht], in any case
(?:/?[FfMmHhTt])*  followed by an optional forward slash separator, and
                   another matching letter, together zero or more times
\]                 match a literal closing square bracket
$                  end of the string
```

### Demo

The idea here is that we match an initial letter, since at least one letter is required for a match.  Then, we match subsequent letters, each of which may or may not be prefixed with a forward slash separator.

Comment: Thank you, that works perfect. I can't accept your answer within 10 mins apparently, but I'll come back to it

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
^\[\/*[FfMmHhTt][FfMmHhTt\/]*\]
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XMWVi1/1) and the [regex graph](https://regex101.com/r/XMWVi1/1):

[image]

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `\[` - `[` char
- `\/*` - zero or more `/`s
- `[FfMmHhTt]` - an allowed letter
- `[FfMmHhTt\/]*` - 0 or more `/` or allowed letters
- `\]`  - a `]` char.

Comment: The OP's comment that `[/]` is not valid might mean that a leading forward slash separator is also not valid, e.g. `[/F]` would not be acceptable.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen There is no requirement to fail `[/h]` string. This solution exactly addresses the problem stated in the question, without adding more restrictions.

Comment: I did in fact want to fail leading and trailing slashes such as `[/t]` or `[h/m/]`. It's my bad for not making that clear.

Answer (score 2):

Another option could be if supported to use a negative lookahead asserting what is on the right is not 1+ times `/` followed by `]`

```
^\[(?!/+\])[FfMmHhTt/]+\]
```

- `^` Start of string
- `\[` Match `[`
- `(?!/+\])` Negative lookahead, assert what is directly on the right is not 1+ times a forward slash followed by `]`
- `[FfMmHhTt/]+` Match 1+ times any of the listed
- `\]` Match `]`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NG78m9/1)